# Initializing Singleton async iOS

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, initialization, singleton

I have a singleton named `YelpService`. Its responsible for retrieving data from Yelp. Of course, each API call must be authorized. The problem is that auth process is async. It would be very redundant if I had to check if yelp client was authorized each time before use of `YelpService`. How can I get around this?

Also, if I add authentication logic inside a method with completion handler and nest inside other method that actually make API calls I get a error: `Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11`

What is a safe and efficient way of storing Yelp client so I can make API calls?
I know its bad to make network calls in init.

```
class YelpService {

    static let _shared = YelpService()

    private let clientId = "id"
    private let clientSecret = "secret"

    var apiClient: YLPClient?

    init() {

        YLPClient.authorize(withAppId: clientId, secret: clientSecret) { (client, error) in
            guard error == nil else {
                print("YELP AUTH ERROR: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }
            guard let client = client else {
                print("YELP AUTH ERROR: CLIENT IS NIL")
                return
            }
            self.apiClient = client
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can block user to further activities mean while your authorise by showing some HUD or Loader to screen

Answer (score 0):

You should not call Singleton class `init()` from outside.

```
class YelpService {

    static let shared = YelpService()

    private let clientId = "id"
    private let clientSecret = "secret"

    var apiClient: YLPClient?

    fileprivate init() {

        YLPClient.authorize(withAppId: clientId, secret: clientSecret) { (client, error) in
            guard error == nil else {
                print("YELP AUTH ERROR: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }
            guard let client = client else {
                print("YELP AUTH ERROR: CLIENT IS NIL")
                return
            }
            self.apiClient = client
            // Here, post notification
        }
    }
}
```

First, from AppDelegate, check `apiClient` is initialized or not, so if not initialized, automatically the first use of shared object will init the Singleton class.

Add notification observer in AppDelegate for `apiClient` initialization.

```
if let apiClient = YelpService.shared.apiClient {
   //Do work
}
```

or do work in notification observer method.